# Car in-dash receiver vs Car speaker bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth-audio, android-auto

I recently bought a in-dash car receiver for android auto. My in-car receiver also has a speaker. Once I start the car, my phone is connecting to in-car receiver over wireless android auto. I can see that my phone is connected to both the in-dash car receiver as well as car Bluetooth speaker. Also, I have disable the "audio" in the bluetooth settings of the car-receiver [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgZ7S.png). Whenever I play a video, the video sound is from the in-car receiver speaker and does not play on the car stereo. When I check the "Media Output" from the quicksetting menu, I can see that the video sound is routed to car Bluetooth stereo only [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySrhm.jpg). How to enable the audio output to my car stereo over bluetooth and stop android auto stealing the streaming from other bluetooths?